# Mocking promise from DynamoDB Documentclient: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm running some unit test cases for aws-dynamodb using aws-sdk-mock. But I'm getting below error:

> UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the
>   request is invalid

Here is what my code looks like.

```js
// Code:
async getUser(email) {
    const params = {
      TableName: 'test',
      Key: {
        email: email
      }
    };
    return await docClient.get(params).promise();
}
```

Here is what my current test looks like:

```js
// Testcase:
it('Get all categories data successfully', async done => {
      AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);
      AWSMock.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'get', (params, callback) => {
        callback(null, { Item: { 
            email: 'test@test.com',
            name: 'Test profile'
          }
        });
      });
      const response = await service.getUserProfile(eventStub.headers.email);
      expect(response).to.equal({Items: { 
            email: 'test@test.com',
            name: 'Test profile'
          }});;
      AWSMock.restore('DynamoDB.DocumentClient');
      done();
});
```

```
UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid

      at Request.extractError (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
      at Request.callListeners (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
      at Request.emit (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
      at Request.emit (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
      at Request.transition (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
      at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
      at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
      at Request.callListeners (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
      at Request.emit (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
      at Request.emit (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
      at Request.transition (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
      at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
      at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
      at Request.callListeners (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
      at callNextListener (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
      at IncomingMessage.onEnd (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:307:13)
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late answer, but for the sake of anyone else who finds this:

As per aws-sdk-mock [readme](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock), see the section with examples on instantiating the AWS service. *The AWS service needs to be instantiated inside the function being tested.*

From the [readme](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock):

> **NB: The AWS Service needs to be initialised inside the function being tested in order for the SDK method to be mocked** e.g for an AWS
> Lambda function example 1 will cause an error region not defined in
> config whereas in example 2 the sdk will be successfully mocked.

In your example, you would probably need to do this:

```
async getUser(email) {
  // instantiate the service inside the function being tested in order for aws-sdk-mock
  // to mock it successfully
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test')
    docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

  const params = {
    TableName: 'test',
    Key: {
      email: email
    }
  }
  return docClient.get(params).promise()
}
```

I run afoul of this mistake too. Hope this helps.